# Select default value is being overridden by state

Tags: reactjs, state

I am currently having a problem with my select dropdown default value being overridden by the state. It is probably something simple that I am missing, but could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

On click of a button, i want to submit the form, but won't pick up the states first value until i change it?

Let me know if I am being unclear or need any additional information.

Thanks!

```js
//Wrapping container containing the state
class ActionsSegment extends Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: '' };
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }
    
      handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        console.log(event.target.value);
      }

    
      handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log((`State passed is: ${this.state.value}`));
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      
      render() {
          const { select, selectLabelTitle } = this.props;
          return (
            <form className="actions-segment" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>        
                <FormSelect 
                    select={select}
                    selectLabelTitle={selectLabelTitle}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.value}
                />
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default ActionsSegment;


//Component containing the select dropdown
<select className="form-select form__flavour-dropdown" onChange={handleChange}>
      {
        select.map((type, index) => (
          <option value={type.title} key={index}>{type.title}</option>
        ))
      }
    </select>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: fyi, you don't need to bind `this` when using ES6 arrow function (inside your constructor), because it does not create a new context. Change `handleSubmit` like you wrote the `handleChange` function, then remove the .bind statements, to make your example more clear. Regarding to your question: Your code looks ok, what button are you referring to?

Comment: Have you considered putting a value attribute on the select tag ?

Comment: @dschu I didn't include it in this example just to shorten it down and get the bits I thought were required :)

Comment: @nubinub I have tried that, but it gets removed by the state :(

Comment: I meant something like `<select value={this.props.value} ...`

Comment: @nubinub yeah I've tried that :( i'm guessing because i set the state as an empty string it overrides it? But I am mapping through data to populate the options..

Comment: You mean that the initial value of the select shouldn't be `''` ?

Comment: @nubinub I used that as a placeholder, it should be the first value of my select, but I need a way of potentially passing up the value to override the '' if possible? Sorry i am fairly new to react

Comment: I guess you can do things like  `this.state = { value: this.props.select[0].title }` or `this.state = { value: this.props.whatEverPropsYouLike }`

Comment: @nubinub that's it! Perfect! Thank you so much!!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can init your select value with any props value you want:

```
this.state = { value: this.props.whatEverPropsYouLike }
```

Or in your case maybe something like that :

```
this.state = { value: this.props.select[0].title }
```